# How can I pass an parameter to a method of an existential type?

Tags: scala, existential-type

Scala code:

```
class AAA[T] {
  def hhh(t: T) = println(t)
}

val a: AAA[_] = new AAA()
```

What can I pass to `a.hhh`? I tried:

```
val b: Any = 111
a.hhh(b) // compilation error!
```

But it has compilation error. If the first part of code can't be changed, how can I make the second one compilable?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: Maybe `a.asInstanceOf[AAA[Int]].hhh(111)`?

Answer (score 2):

All you can do is wrapping it to something like:

```
def ggg[T](t: T)= a.asInstanceOf[AAA[T]].hhh(t)

ggg(111) // prints 111
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, given an `AAA[T]` for an unknown type `T`, you need a `T`. It should be obvious why `val b: Any = 111` doesn't work: since `T` can be anything it can be e.g. `String`.

So to pass something, it has to have every possible type `T` at once, and so it can only have one type: `Nothing`.

```
val b: Nothing = throw new Exception
a.hhh(b) // compiles!
```

For this `hhh` signature this will always throw an exception, since there are no actual values of type `Nothing`. But you could get something more reasonable by modifying it: e.g. taking the argument by name, taking `List[T]` (in which case `Nil` could be passed), etc.